# Regular expression for find and replace double “NON BREAKING SPACE”

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to find with jQuery or Javascript the way to detect exactly the occurrence of two consecutive non-breaking spaces.

```
text = text.replace(/&nbsp;&nbsp;/g, "");

text = text.replace(/&nbsp;{2}/g, "");
```

For instance this is correct for me :

```
HELLO&nbsp;&nbsp;WORLD
```

But this lines didn't work

```
but no HELLO&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;WORLD
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: `text.replace(/&nbsp;&nbsp;/g, "");` works for me : http://jsfiddle.net/G8Mge/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
var repl = text.replace(/(&nbsp;){2}/g, "");
//=> HELLOWORLD
```

Your regex: `/&nbsp;{2}/` is effectively trying to match `&nbsp;;`

To remove all instances of `&nbsp;` use:

```
var repl = text.replace(/(&nbsp;)+/g, "");
```

Comment: You don't want the `g` - otherwise it will select consecutive groups in the second example.

Comment: `'HELLO&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;WORLD'.replace(/(&nbsp;){2}/g, "");` is `HELLOWORLD` but without `g` you won't get same result.

Comment: I see your point. OP is a little vague on if he wants to remove all instances of `&nbsp;`, or just a group of two only.

Comment: Yes that's why I provided both options in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use just like this to replace space only coming from `&nbsp;`

```
text.replace(/&nbsp;/g, "");
```

No need to use two times `&nbsp;` as g is for global search.

---

And this will allow you to remove any type of unwanted space:

```
text.replace(/\s/g, "");
```